# Linux /dev/null write operation succeeded

Tags: linux, unix, stdout

I was reading a Wikipedia entry which says : In Unix-like operating systems, /dev/null or the null device is a special file that discards all data written to it but "**reports that the write operation succeeded.**"

There are two parts to this statement. First part is clear that its a null file. I am not clear about second part of the sentence, where/how can i find the write operation succeeded?

Comment: Data written to `/dev/null` is quietly accepted and discarded. It behaves this way because it's *useful*; if you have output you want to ignore, you can send it to `/dev/null`. `/dev/full` acts like `/dev/null` on input, but attempts to write to it always fail.

Comment: @slashmais: Actually it won't. I think you're thinking if=/dev/zero

Comment: @yoones: yes you are right, mixed up with /dev/zero :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/dev/null is a special file that doesn't store any data. It means you will always succeed at writing in this file, no matter how much data you want to write.

Said differently, you won't get any error when trying to write in this file.

Comment: thanks. You are right and my understanding was the same but what about the line "Reports that write operation succeeded" Is it true or is it a mistake on wiki entry? Or is there any other inner meaning to it

Comment: If you program in C, the write call returns the number of bytes written, or -1 on error. That's the error they are talking about on the wiki (error that won't happen with /dev/null).